# How to upload folder in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

Hi i wanted to upload folder and move to some destination is it possible doing in php ? or at least i can read the folder name and create same folder in divination and copy all files into created folder.

Comment: Please provide us with any code you tried so far. Thx

Comment: buddy i am not getting any code :( so asking

Comment: from where to where are you copying these files ? from the users computer on to the server or within the server ? if you using ajax to do this (from the users's to the server)  you will need to loop through the files in the folder and upload each. so instead of that simply ask the user to make a zip file and make him select it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the new HTML5 directory capabilities. Just put the directory attributes in your input field. After you got the directory server-side, you can do everything you want with it.

URL for a simple guide:

```
http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/directory-upload-using-html-5-and-php.html
```